# AVAUdioPlayer - changing current URL

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

In my audio player app, if I hit the fast forward button - the player must find the next song in the playlist and play it. What I do is I get the URL from the next song, and try to put it in the background (background is an instance of AVAudioPlayer*) url field, but that property is read only. So what I'm actually doing - I'm calling the initWithContentsOfURL method (again) to set the URL like this :

```
[self.background initWithContentsOfURL:
[[_playlist.collection objectAtIndex:currentIndex] songURL] error:nil];
```

Is this legit? I mean, the compiler tells me that the expression result is unused, but it actually works.
Is there another way of doing it? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have checked 4 Apple samples, they are using AVAudioPlayer to play one song only. However, your result looks very interesting and impressive! Please let us know, are you stopping the playback before reinitializing object with the same address, are you starting the new audio session ?

As for me, I'd not put the playback and app stability in a risk doing something not mentioned in the documentation but , but to be on the bright side would use the AVAudioPlayer class as it seems the most right, which gives us:

- use the error variable to track the possible errors
- stop the playing AVAudioPlayer instance, initialize a new instance of AVAudioPlayer and set it to the property letting an old-one to be deallocated automatically.

And you probably know yourself, that

```
self.background = [self.background initWithContentsOfURL::
```

will remove the warning for you.

Comment: Yes, I stop the playback, set the new URL and then set it to play. Thanks for the hint on how to remove the warning though, much appreciated ;-)

Comment: Hi @nemesis, the other answer looks like the best way to achieve your goal, can you mark it as accepted ?

Comment: Heelo @A-Live. I don't want to accept the other answer because it does not answer my question. I wanted to know how I would change the current URL of an AVAudioPlayer, and not play items sequentially.

Comment: @nemesis Up to you of course, I think it can be done by adding a new URL as the next playlist item, advancing playback and removing the first item. You'd have one item at playlist this way, but yeah, extra changes.

Answer (score 17):

For playing more than one URL, or effectively changing the URL, use the subclass `AVQueuePlayer`.

> AVQueuePlayer is a subclass of AVPlayer you use to play a number of items in sequence.

**Example:**

```
NSString *fooVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tommy" ofType:@"mov"];
NSString *barVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pamela" ofType:@"mp4"];

AVPlayerItem *fooVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fooVideoPath]];
AVPlayerItem *barVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:barVideoPath]];

self.queuePlayer = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fooVideoItem, barVideoItem,nil]];
[self.queuePlayer play];

// things happening...

[self.queuePlayer advanceToNextItem];
```

Comment: This question is about audio. Would this work with audio?