# Play music according to scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play theme music in continuous loop according to the scene in Sprite Kit. So far I am doing this:

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer();

func playBackgroundMusic() -> () {

    var error: NSError?
    let backgroundMusicURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Home", ofType: "wav")!)
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: backgroundMusicURL, error: &error)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}
```

And it is working. But now I want to play a different theme music in another theme. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710679/avaudioplayer-changing-current-url), I have to use AVQueuePlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer. But AVQueuePlayer doesn't have methods like stop() or number of loops.

Any idea how to change sounds when switching to different scenes?

Comment: have you tried simply stopping the player, then creating a new one with a new audio file?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I am creating the player in AppDelegate.swift class so that I can control it from everywhere inside the app and pause it when the app is paused.

Comment: yeah but that doesn't answer my question. You can always just stop the player and play a new file. If it's required by AVAudioPlayer to create a new instance, do that and replace the existing one.